# Ignoring locks in SVN commit

Tags: svn, locking

How to make SVN to ignore the lock errors it faces when committing a collection of files? Pointing out the locked files, each time you want to commit the whole repository is time consuming and SVN fails when you commit the whole folder since there are some locked files in it.

Any solution?

Comment: I would try to find out why it's locking everything and then failing to commit. That isn't supposed to happen... you could write a script to go through and delete the locks, but I think you'd be much better off finding out why it's not doing what it's supposed to do in the first place.

Comment: What do you mean by "ignore locks"? Should it silently not commit the locked files? Silently override the lock? (I can't come up with a scenario where ignoring the locks is a good idea.)

Comment: The scenario is simple, you might want to lock some of your configuration files so everyone can have them but not commit their changes back to the server. Configuration files are environment specific after all.

Comment: But in the case of config files, those shouldn't be changing that often anyways. In the situation you described, the lock is there so that explicit action is required to commit changes to files that are protected.

Comment: You are missing the point. Consider you and me both have checked out a project. In order to test the project locally, we both have made changes to a configuration file so that it meets our computers settings locally. Sure we should not commit the file back to the repository, so we'll put a lock on that particular file. Now, through out the project lifetime, each time we are about to commit, we have to leave the locked configuration file out of our commit list, or it will fail. I believe this takes too much effort, especially if there are multiple such files scattered across the project.

Comment: Perhaps this need of mine requires a feature other than locks. A feature like "one way files (OWF)". In OWF, one can only read (svn update) from server and all the commits on OWF go to waste (swallowed by a black hole). Sure there might be times which you actually need to update the OWF, but it should be done in a special way indicating that you are aware of the fact that it's changing an OWF. Or maybe I'm asking too much!!

Answer (score 1):

Just an idea how to change the situation in a positive way for you (I have read all the comments, so I think the main problem are files that should be examples from the server, but normally not changed locally).

The base  idea is here to give the files that should be examples, but not real configuration files a suffix to just denote that. It is similar to the repository hooks you get in each installation of Subversion with the suffix `.tmpl`. These indicate that a repository hook could be implemented by that, but you have to **manually** change the ending of that file.

In your case, the following should be done:

1. Find the files you only want to be "one way".
2. Give them an ending, so that every one sees that these files are just examples.
3. Have a build process or do manual a copy of that file.
4. Tell the people what and how to change.
5. Add to your directory in the "ignore list" the file with the name its normally used locally, so the file will not be added by accident to the repository again.
6. You may even add a pre-commit hook to ensure that these files are not added any more.
7. You have to have a build process that takes you example files and copies them to the real name for the deployment then. But it is a good idea anyway to have a build process for such tasks.